# How to set path in Jenkins for directory having Android AVD?

Tags: android, jenkins, android-emulator-plugin

When I try to build my android workspace using Jenkins Build Now option, It will show the error like

```
[android] Cannot start Android emulator: Could not start AVD 'Nexus_4', as it could 
not be found at 'C:\Windows\system32\config\systemprofile\.android\avd\Nexus_4.avd'
Recording test results
Finished: FAILURE
```

By default, directory for android avd is `/users/user.name/.android`. How can I provide this avd path to Jenkins? It always try to search avd in above given Windows location automatically.

Note : I am using Windows-7 OS.

Comment: Hi, Try creating another AVD

Comment: @NadirB from AVD manager or by using Jenkins? If you are suggesting using Jenkins, then it would be the alternative not the solution.

Comment: did you try to search by hand the emulator does it exist within that path ?

Comment: There is no any emulator in that path and I don't want to use that path too. I want to set the path of my choice but I am not able to find the option for it.

Comment: ok check this link https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zm6ntUt-vqY

Comment: Are you using Master-Slave configuration or is it a standalone Jenkins?

Comment: @Technext I just have installed Jenkins and have installed Android emulator plugin. Moreover, I have set the required path of JDK, ANT and Android SDK. Do I need to configure something more? My project is on PC only so I have set workspace path too for that.

Comment: Can you run the command from command line?

Comment: What command? By command line, you mean Jenkins script console or windows command prompt?

Comment: Command to start Android emulator from Win command prompt.

Comment: Yes I am able to do that. What my actual problem is Jenkins **automatically** try to find avd in 'C:\Windows\system32\config\systemprofile\.android\avd\', while avds are in "C:\Users\user.name\.android\avd" folder. So I want to change that Jenkins default path to my avd path.

Comment: The PATH that Jenkins is searching for is the `SYSTEM` profile path because Jenkins must be running as SYSTEM user. This you can verify when you will go to `Log On` tab as described in my answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If your command runs fine on Win command prompt as user 'X', then you should run Jenkins with the same user.

This can be achieved by performing following steps:
 1. Run > services.msc (Enter)
2. Select Jenkins service. Right-click and select Properties
3. Click on `Log On` tab
4. Select user 'X' and provide credentials
5. Restart Jenkins

In your case, the user 'X' seems to be *user.name* since the path to AVD as mentioned by you is `/users/user.name/.android`

[image]

Comment: I have followed your answer and now its not giving that windows path error. So my path issue is resolved. Though I am not able to run existing emulator but I will try for that. As it has solved my path and user problem, I am accepting this answer.  :)