# Permission denied error while running from jenkins

Tags: python, jenkins, google-cloud-platform, virtualenv, google-compute-engine

Hey I'm to run my script on locally -

I can run the script from my python virtual environment

```
cd /home/hhh/src/d_platform && /home/hhh/venvs/bdp/bin/python -m test.test1.test12
```

I tried to run the same from jenkins

Its giving the following error

```
context.load_verify_locations(ca_certs)
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied
```

Answer (score 0):

it seems like a permission issue from Jenkins instance.

Have you tried to follow the steps describe from the user "Technext" [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25863745/failed-to-run-python-scripts-with-jenkins)

Furthermore, going referring to other case [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37219141/permissionerror-errno-13-permission-denied) that user "Ian Marks"

Following the cases described above it should work, hope this can be useful for your situation.