# Jenkins variable for define my AVD location

Tags: android, jenkins, android-virtual-device

I working on lunch Android app on system emulator in Jenkins. I defined my Android SDK location as **Environment variables** in Jenkins with: `ANDROID_SDK = " "`

My AVDs are created in another location and I want to find Variable to define AVD location. And regard this [article](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Android+Emulator+Plugin) there is no variable for AVD location and always it is looking for AVD in this `C:\Windows\system32\config\systemprofile\.android\avd\` but how I can change it for another location?

I also tried [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25802280/1498586). but with this solution the path is wrong too:

```
Could not start AVD 'Nexus_5X_API_24', as it could not be found at 'C:\Users\myUser\.android\avd\.android\avd\Nexus_5X_API_24.avd'
Finished: FAILURE
```

although my path is `C:\Users\myUser\.android\avd\Nexus_5X_API_24.avd`

Comment: is your issue resolved ?

Comment: @jiteshmohite not yet

Answer (score -1):

I guess you are trying to configure AVD path in Global Tool Configuration.

Actually you could configure it in Global Settings - Environment variables, and use $xxx(linux/unix) or %xxx%(windows) in your shell (xxx means Environment variables key)

Comment: would you explain with an example. you mean in jenkins or windows?